# Unresolved external symbol _aiGetMaterialTextureCount when trying to compile Assimp

Tags: c++, linker-errors, assimp

I am trying to use Assimp in my C++ game engine but it fails to link. I know that "unresolved external symbol" means that the linker is unable to find the functions, but I know that I've set up the project settings correctly. I compiled the latest version of Assimp from source (v 5.0.1) and linked to
assimp-vc142-mtd.lib, IrrXMLd.lib, and zlibd.lib (although I think I only need to link to the first one). Despite that, I still receive this error. I also tried compiling Assimp in Release Mode and linking against assimp-vc142-mt.lib but still receive the error.

[Here is a screenshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk88T.jpg)

Also, I know that this error only shows up when I actually write code using Assimp, such as:

```
Assimp::Importer importer;
const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(filename, aiProcess_Triangulate
    | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices);

aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[i];
    textureList[i] = nullptr;

    if (material->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE))
    {
        aiString path;
        if (material->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0, &path) == aiReturn_SUCCESS)
        {
            // do stuff...
        }
    }
```

If I remove the above code, then I no longer get any errors, but that doesn't help because then I can't actually use the library. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any other missing references from the assimp code which you have used?

Comment: No, all the errors are shown in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your linker to link the assimp dll. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have encountered the same issue before, and the reason for that error was that: my Cmake created the solution in x64 platform by default, while my project is running on a x86 (Win32) platform.

You should either check your project's targeted platform, or you should switch your platform to whichever platform that Cmake creates your solution.

I hope that information may help.